# stored procedure in mysql not returning multiple result sets

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I get 2 result sets in the following stored procedure.

```
delimiter //
create procedure t2()
begin
    select * from itut_user limit 6;

    select * from itut_student limit 6;
end //
delimiter ;
```

When I call this, it gives me only the result of the second query. Please help.

Comment: which method you are using PDO or mysqli

Comment: I am not using any method. I just simply created and executed it on workbench like so: `call t2()`. It should give me 2 resultsets. Is there a global variable I need to set before mysql gives me both resultsets? i don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Once put this `SET SESSION sql_mode = '';` code before select query then try

Comment: not working :(. I tried.